# what is a pseudorandom cache mentioned in ethereum yellow paper

Tags: ethereum-classic, hash-algorithm, ethash

in ethereum yellow paper it says:

```
"There exists a seed which can be computed for each
block by scanning through the block headers up until that
point. From the seed, one can compute a pseudorandom
cache, Jcacheinit bytes in initial size. Light clients store
the cache."
```

what does it mean by pseudorandom cache? is it because it is using a RandMemoHash for generating the cache?

Comment: The paragraph is from section 11.5.1 "Ethash". It is a large chunk of memory that is easy to recreate from a small seed. From https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash#cache-generation it uses a version of RandMemoHash.